# C++ Multiple definitions even though only one definition is given

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, multiple-definition-error

I'm trying to make a small unordered map that I can use to store keys and values permanently, as a sort of dictionary. The type `TengwarChar` is just an object with two values, a string and an enum, and later I'll add methods too. The header I use is as follows:

```
#ifndef TENGWARLIBRARY_H
#define TENGWARLIBRARY_H

#include "tengwarchar.h"
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, TengwarChar> CharMap;

extern const CharMap numbers = {
    {"0", TengwarChar("ð", SHORT)},
    {"1", TengwarChar("ñ", SHORT)},
    {"2", TengwarChar("ò", SHORT)},
    {"3", TengwarChar("ó", SHORT)},
    {"4", TengwarChar("ô", SHORT)},
    {"5", TengwarChar("õ", SHORT)},
    {"6", TengwarChar("ö", SHORT)},
    {"7", TengwarChar("÷", SHORT)},
    {"8", TengwarChar("ø", SHORT)},
    {"9", TengwarChar("ù", SHORT)}
 };

std::string translateFromEnglishToTengwar(std::string str);
std::string translateFromTengwarToEnglish(std::string str);

#endif // TENGWARLIBRARY_H
```

Then, I have a simple testing cpp file that goes along with it:

```
#include "tengwarlibrary.h"

std::string translateFromEnglishToTengwar(std::string str)
{
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), (int (*)(int))std::tolower);
    return str;
}

std::string translateFromTengwarToEnglish(std::string str)
{
    return "Hello world.";
}
```

The problem is, I keep getting 'multiple definition of numbers[abi:cxx11]' errors, when invoke `translateFromTengwarToEnglish` in my main function, even though I'm fairly certain I have only defined it once, in my header file, using header guards too. In case it might help, here is my humble main cpp file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#include <iostream>

#include "utils/tengwarlibrary.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    std::string s = "BlaH FElfeFEJI, IEORlfj";
    std::cout<<translateFromEnglishToTengwar(s)<<std::endl;

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: You can only *declare* symbols with external linkage in a header file.  Their definition needs to be in the translation units using them.

Comment: @HenriMenke I have gotten the same error when I remove the `extern const` bit and just assume it's a global variable. I don't really want to have to put a definition into the source file when I can use an initializer in the header.

Comment: @AndrewLalis You cannot. The way you wrote it, each source file implicitly gets a *definition* of the numbers array. You should *declare* the array in the header and *define* it (without the extern keyword) in exactly one source file.

Comment: @HellmarBecker so should I just make an 'init' function in one of my sources that defines all the arrays I'll need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) §3.1.2

> A declaration is a definition unless it declares a function without specifying the function’s body, it contains the extern specifier or a linkage-specification and neither an
>   initializer nor a function-body ...

Declaration of `numbers` in the header file `tengwarlibrary.h` is extern declaration with initializer. So it is also a definition.

As you have included `tengwarlibrary.h` in two source files (one where `translateFromTengwarToEnglish()` is defined and where `main()` defined) both of them has the definition of `numbers`. Hence, the error.

To solve this problem declare `number` with `extern` in header file and initialize it in a single source file.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the most recent versions of GCC. In my case, this error appeared while running a C project on a docker container (Alpine image). However, it did not appear when I ran the same project using an older GCC version (9.4.0).

What fixed it for me was adding the `extern` keyword to the global variables/functions that presented the issue.